# How to run socket code in another threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

In my application I have **adapter** and in this **adapter** I should call **socket**.
I want call **socket** in **another thread** and not call in **`MainThread`**.
I write **socket** code, but I don't know how can I call this in **another thread**.

**My socket code :**

```
mSocket.on("finish", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        try {
            Constants.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("socketLogs", args[0] + "");
                    try {
                        startTimer();
                        final FinishResponse finishResponse = new Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), FinishResponse.class);
                        countDownerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        winnerLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        bidCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        offerCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        price.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        timeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        userPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        winnerLay.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                        //if (finishResponse.getRes().getWinnerAvatar() != null && !finishResponse.getRes().getWinnerAvatar().equals("")) {
                            Glide.with(context)
                                    .load(Constants.SERVER + finishResponse.getRes().getWinnerAvatar())
                                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                    .into(User);
                       /* } else {
                            User.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));
                        }*/
                        edtUserName.setText(finishResponse.getRes().getWinnerName());
                        edtUserName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
                        txtStartPrice.setText("Sell");
                        txtStartPrice.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.TextColorGreen));
                        txtStartPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                        try {
                            String[] splitDate = finishResponse.getRes().getEnd().split(" ");
                            String[] dateSpliet = splitDate[0].split("-");
                            TimeUtils timeUtils = new TimeUtils(Integer.parseInt(dateSpliet[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateSpliet[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateSpliet[2]));
                            txtPrice.setText(splitDate[1] + "  " + timeUtils.getIranianDate());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
});
```

I write above code in `getView` method from **Adapter**.
But I want write above code in **another thread** , and **not run in MainThread**.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create new Thread for this

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do stuff
            }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

I would give some recommendations concerning your code. First, it is bad to call Socket in adapter in **getView**. You should Call it in fragment or Activity (if you don't use MVP or some other architecture).

Next big problem is that you have current activity saved in constants

```
Constants.currentActivity
```

It will cause memory leaks, you activity will live even if you close it, and your app will have many problems with such approach.

Comment: Thanks my friend. if i call socket in fragment, how can i update adapter when receive socket response? i use ArrayAdapter and ListView . please help me

Comment: You can do two things:
1) when you receive data from socket, update List of Adapter and call 
adapter.setItems (newArrayList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
and adapter will refresh itself
2) or just set new adapter to a list.

Comment: How can i it? can you help me and send to me code? please

Comment: I write this code for call adapter : `AuctionTodayListAdapter adapter = new AuctionTodayListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_auction_large_new, Constants.auction.getToday());
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Great,
1) add method updateItems(Arraylist<> items) to your AuctionTodayListAdapter, that updates auction list. 
2) setup socket in fragment/activity, when you get socket response in fragment/activity to call adapter's **updateItems** method, this will update your list inside adapter.
3) call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**  this will update your items.

Comment: Thanks my dear friend for you great help <3 . can you send to me your skype ID? Thanks

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Unfortunately I use Skype only for job and don't have enough time to answer questions. Feel free to ask questions about this problem here. I will try to find time to answer.

One more recommendation - use Recyclerview instead of Listview :)